# Formatting an Array in php (3 into one)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So currently I have an array that pulls data based on an attribute and it puts the data in its own seperate array. What I need to do is to put these 3 arrays into one, so if one of them is null, it won't give me errors. It should be fairly simply but I can't wrap my head around it.

```
 //CV eqpValue
 if (is_array(FullDataResponse->dlr->DesignLayoutRecord)) {
    foreach(FullDataResponse->dlr->DesignLayoutRecord as $DesignLayoutRecord_key => $DesignLayoutRecord_value ) {
            if ($DesignLayoutRecord_value->cktEqpOptions->CktEqpOptions && is_array($DesignLayoutRecord_value->cktEqpOptions->CktEqpOptions)) {
                    foreach ($DesignLayoutRecord_value->cktEqpOptions->CktEqpOptions as $cv_obj)
                           {
                                if($cv_obj->attribute === 'CDR')
                                        {
                                             $this->cvCDRList[] = array("cdr" => $cv_obj->eqpValue);
                                        }

                                if($cv_obj->attribute === 'CUSTOMER')
                                        {
                                             $this->cvCustomerList[] = array("customer" => $cv_obj->eqpValue);
                                        }

                            if($cv_obj->attribute === 'LEASE LINE')
                                        {
                                             $this->cvphoneList[] = array("phoneNumber" => $cv_obj->eqpValue);
                                        }  
                                       }
                                    }
                              }
                             }
```

See how they are currently put into separate arrays like cvCDRList, cvCustomerList, and cvphoneList? How would I put them into a single array? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking for. Are you trying to change cvCDRList, cvCustomerList, and cvphoneList to say newList? What format do you want the final array to be in?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I want the "newList"[] to consist of fields cvCDRList, cvCustomerList and cvphoneList. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use array_merge.

```
<?php

   $array1 = array("a12","a12","a13");
   $array2 = array("a21","a22","a23");
   $array3 = array("a31","a32","a33");

   $finalArray = array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3);              
   foreach( $finalArray as $key => $value ){
       echo $key."=>".$value."<br>";
   } 

?>
```

You can create another property called "allAtributes" .
When you finalize to fill your 3 arrays you can call to another method of class than make the merge between 3 array.

The finally you will have got like this :

```
allAtributes (array)=>{ 
        ["cdr"](array)=> {
            ['cdrkey1'] = cdrAtt1 ,
            ['cdrKey2'] = cdrAtt2 ...
        },
        ["customer"](array)=> {
            ['customerkey1'] = customerAtt1 ,
            ['customerKey2'] = customerAtt2 ...
        },
        ["phoneNumber"](array)=> {
            ['phoneNumberkey1'] = phoneNumberAtt1 ,
            ['phoneNumberKey2'] = phoneNumberAtt2 ...
        } 
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how that would be used for my exact example? I am trying it out but it is giving me issues.

Comment: Ahh, I just added this into the for so it gave an error. Had to make sure it was outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You only must declare an array an add the other three arrays with the function array_merge into loops